# How much Currencies support in Stripe Payment Gateway for one account?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I need the following Currencies for payment processing for my website.

```
1). USD
2). CDN
3). EUR
4). GBP
```

I have read the documentation. But i got only one currency possible for one stripe account.
But i am not sure about this.

Is there possible to process these currencies by single account?.

And How its achievable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They do have support here https://support.stripe.com/email , ask them and they will reply you with exactly what all you can achieve with an account . I have used recurly , pretty happy with it .

Comment: This may be of some relavance to you https://stripe.com/blog/new-currencies